# Extract RegExp string from binary in windows batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, binary, cmd, findstr

a little problem keeps bugging me for couple of days. I'm trying to extract a string I can define with regexp from a *.exe binary, text like "1.01.01.00T123" into a environment variable for further use.
I've found the string with

```
findstr /i [0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][T][0-9][0-9][0-9] name.exe>outp.bin
```

now it's my string in a little bit smaller binary, maybe 200bytes. Then I was trying to use an output of findstr in a "for /f", but what delimiter should I use for the binary, nothing is guaranteed. Even dots and blanks can come and go.
Something like:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=^." %%a in ('findstr /i [0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9] name.exe') do (
echo %%a
echo %%b
echo %%c
echo %%d
)
```

It works only halfway - the first is too long, an the last part "xxTxxx" isn't a token by this definition. Besides a dot can also happen inside of a binary, and not only in my string.
I thought of something like shorten the outp.bin in loop by cutting always the first byte and then check if my string is at the start of the outp.bin. But still haven't found way to do this. Is it possible?
Is there any way, that's less complex to just copy my regex result into a variable?
I hope missed some magic command for the regexp in a standard command shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nearly impossible to do what you want with pure batch because your binary may include nul bytes and batch cannot process null bytes. But the problem can easily be solved using VBS or JScript and regular expressions.

Here is a very crude VBS solution, with lots of room for improvement. But it works.

**findStr.vbs**

```
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\dT\d\d\d"
Set matches = myRegExp.Execute(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll())
For Each match In matches
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(match.value)
Next
```

Call the script with CSCRIPT and redirect input to your exe file.

```
<name.exe cscript //nologo findStr.vbs
```

You could use batch to process the results via FOR /F.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('^<name.exe cscript //nologo findStr.vbs') do echo %%A
```

***UPDATE - 2015-08-26***

You could easily solve this with [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a pure script based regex processing utlity (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

The following simply lists the value(s) found in the file. Note that the `/M` option is required because of possible null bytes in the exe.

```
call jrepl "\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\dT\d\d\d" $0 /jmatch /m /f name.exe
```

To capture the value in a variable (or the last value if there are multiple occurrences):

```
for %%A in (
  'jrepl "\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\dT\d\d\d" $0 /jmatch /m /f name.exe'
) do set "str=%%A"
```

Comment: Another option might be to use [`strings`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) for extracting the printable characters and pipe its output into `findstr`.

Comment: @dbenham, thanks a lot! I've given up on the clean shell script and your vbs does the job excellent! Works like a charm, I'll pack the vbs lines in my cmd script then will >>echo me a temp vbs-script file, and do stuff to my nasty binaries.
Btw, what do you mean by "nearly impossible"? :-)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks! Say please, what do you mean by "use strings"? How does it go? And still, even if I can show me only printable charachters, I can't guarantee even single consequence aside of my RegExp-String, so actually. 
Only thing I came up with would be shorten my binary clip always for one byte and then look if "findstr /b" brings any positive results. Then if it is shorten the rest from its end and then look with "findstr /e". But somehow I haven't found yet the way to cut one byte pro iteration.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, sorry, it was not a very bright question of me. :-) You posted a link :-) I see now.

Comment: @sangesi - By "nearly impossible" I mean that it might be possible with pure native batch, but it would require heroic efforts, a lot of code, and would probably be very slow. The only commands I can think of that can process nul bytes are CERTUTIL -DUMP and FC /B, but I wouldn't want to build a solution around those when it is so much easier using some other scripting language.

Comment: @dbenham, this was just out of pure curiosity, the almost magic complexity of some one liners in native batch fascinates me as it is.
I'll gladly take the your VB as a solution. Many thanks again!